Custom JSON Console Formatter in OpenTelemetry: How to align a Custom Log Exporter
I have two services: one in .NET and one in Java. I have a custom log formatter in the Java service and I want to align the .NET app to match this Java service.
LogTemplatejava.json:
{
    "@timestamp": {
        "$resolver": "timestamp",
        "pattern": {
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    },
    "log.level": {
        "$resolver": "level",
        "field": "name"
    },
    "process.thread.name": {
        "$resolver": "thread",
        "field": "name"
    },
    "log.logger": {
        "$resolver": "logger",
        "field": "name"
    },
    "traceId": {
        "$resolver": "mdc",
        "key": "trace_id"
    },
    "spanId": {
        "$resolver": "mdc",
        "key": "span_id"
    },
    "tenantId": {
        "$resolver": "mdc",
        "key": "tenantId"
    },
    "tenantName": {
        "$resolver": "mdc",
        "key": "tenantName"
    },
    "service.name": "${spring:spring.application.name:-}",
    "service.instance.id": "${env:POD_NAME:-}",
    "message": {
        "$resolver": "message",
        "stringified": true
    },
    "error.type": {
        "$resolver": "exception",
        "field": "className"
    },
    "error.message": {
        "$resolver": "exception",
        "field": "message"
    },
    "error.stack_trace": {
        "$resolver": "exception",
        "field": "stackTrace",
        "stackTrace": {
            "stringified": true
        }
    }
}

log4j.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="FP-cloud-configuration">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:FpLogTemplate.json" />
        </Console>
        <Async name="AsyncConsoleAppender">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Format of logs after this config:
{"@timestamp":"2024-07-22T06:36:30.035+0000","log.level":"INFO","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"com.authService","service.name":"auth","service.instance.id":"","message":"Starting AuthenticationService using Java 21.0.3 with PID 19723 (/home/user/IdeaProjects-auth/target/classes started by user in /home/user/IdeaProjects/auth)"}
{"@timestamp":"2024-07-22T06:36:30.039+0000","log.level":"INFO","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"com.authService","service.name":"auth","service.instance.id":"","message":"The following 1 profile is active: \"lst\""}

I want to align my .NET app's logging format to match that of my Java service. I have attempted to create a CustomJsonFormatter, but I'm unable to retrieve the service name, messages, or span IDs. Additionally, I need to handle errors effectively.
public class CustomJsonConsoleFormatter : BaseProcessor<LogRecord>
{
    public override void OnEnd(LogRecord data)
    {
        var logEntry = new
        {
            @timestamp = data.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            log_level = data.LogLevel.ToString(),
            process_thread_name = data.CategoryName, // Adjust if needed to get the actual thread name
            log_logger = data.CategoryName,
            service_name = data.Attributes?.FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.Key == "service.name").Value?.ToString(),
            message = data.Body,
            error = data.Exception != null
                ? new
                {
                    type = data.Exception.GetType().Name,
                    message = data.Exception.Message,
                    stack_trace = data.Exception.StackTrace
                }
                : null
        };

        string logJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(logEntry);
        Console.WriteLine(logJson);
    }
}

In startup.cs
_ = services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
    {
        options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
        options.IncludeScopes = true;
        options.ParseStateValues = true;
        options.AddProcessor(new CustomJsonConsoleFormatter());
    });
});

How logs are look like:
{"timestamp":"2024-07-22T09:04:48.084Z","log_level":"Information","process_thread_name":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","log_logger":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","service_name":null,"message":"Now listening on: {address}","error":null}


The service name is a resource attributes and therefore come from the resource builder, not the LogRecord.

I would also recommend you move both to OTLP instead of console as it's an anti-pattern with OpenTelemetry.

@MartinDotNet Thank you for your answer. Would be great if you give some link or resources that can help me to achieve desired format of logs and why it`s antipattern

OTLP is the standard when using OpenTelemetry, we don't talk about using console for anything other than debugging due to the inefficiencies involved in using it in production scenarios. Here's the way that the console exporter currently does resources. https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console/ConsoleLogRecordExporter.cs#L138

Thank you for the insights. I understand that OTLP is the preferred choice for production environments. I’m interested in learning more about this. But i cant understand what should i do now. what "both" should i move to OTLP and how to achieve this

Both Java and .NET have OTLP exporters, and most backends for telemetry accept OTLP now.

@MartinDotNet I can make changes only in .Net app. java service is private and i need only to align to it

You don't need to make code changes for Java, it works using an agent style approach so it's loaded directly into the JVM.

@MartinDotNet thanks for your assistance. I believe I need to investigate this further to better understand the flow of observability in this context. Now i have a goal to align console logs despite it`s antipattern

@MartinDotNet I guess would be great if you can guide on how to achieve this log format alignment. Any specific resources, examples, or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated or you see only OTLP option?

I've provided the link for the current console exporter, there's not much more I can do.
